# Reverse a nested list along with the elements in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, nested, reverse

I have the following list:

```
lst = ['123', '456', [['123', '456']], ['123', '456']]
```

I want to reverse the list with the elements of each list also in the reversed order. The output should look like:

```
lst = [['654', '321'], [['654', '321']], '654', '321']
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried using divide and conquer method but was not getting correct output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def recursive_reverse(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x[::-1]
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [recursive_reverse(i) for i in x][::-1]
    return x


lst = ["123", "456", [["123", "456"], "hello"], ["123", "456"]]
print(recursive_reverse(lst))
```

prints out

```
[['654', '321'], ['olleh', ['654', '321']], '654', '321']
```

Comment: nice answer - you can get rid of `"".join(x[::-1])` as `x[::-1]` will be sufficient